# I saw this piece of code in a coding book and the output was 3, 5, 7, 9. Can someone explain to me why number 1 is not displayed in the output?

Tags: java

Here is the code that I tried in VS Code:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 10)
if((i++) % 2 == 0)     
System.out.println(i);
```

And the output was:
3
5
7
9

Comment: Why do you think it should print 1? I mean the value gets initialized with 1 and then incremented with `i++` to 2 before any print statement in the code can be reached. So i can obviously not be 1 at the time of printing.

Comment: Because that is what is written there. What do *you* expect and *why* do you expect the code to do something else?

Comment: I think the question is clear, what clarity are we looking for

Comment: I took the (i++) as a variable on its own, so first  when (i++) % 2 ==0 which is true because (1+1) % 2 does give you 0, the System.out.println(i) should print i which is 1. That was my misunderstanding. Plus if the i++ increases i to 2, shouldn't it print 2? Basically my problem was: why does this piece of code print 3 5 7 9 and not something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first iteration of the loop `i == 1`.

`i++` increments `i` to 2, but returns 1.

Therefore `if((i++) % 2 == 0)` evaluates to `false` (since 1 is not even), and nothing is printed.

In the next iteration, `i++` increments `i` to 3, but returns 2.

Therefore `if((i++) % 2 == 0)` evaluates to `true` (since 2 is even), and `3` is printed.

`1` would not be printed even if `i` was printed on the first iteration of the loop, since `i++` increments `i` to `2` before the `println` statement.